# how to make code run if a exception is caught regardless of it, but have some line for specific exceptions at the same time

Tags: python, exception

let's say i have some code :

```
try :
  JumpOverFence()

except TooShortError :
  print("Wow, you're too short for this obstacle")
  ABunchOfLinesThatSaysGoTrain()

except FellError :
  print("Wow, you fell! go work on your balance!")
  ABunchOfLinesThatSaysGoTrain()
```

So basically i just have a bunch of lines that i want to run regardless of the error, and a few lines that i want to run for a specific kind of exception, hopefully i was clear.Thanks!

Comment: So what exactly is the question? What is wrong with your current code?

Comment: my question is that if there a built-in way of making my code execute code if a exception is caught regardless of what it is, and then have some custom lines of code. executes for specific exceptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a function.

```
def GoTrain(msg):
 print(msg)
 print("Go do some training!")
 # more lines here

try :
  JumpOverFence()

except TooShortError :
  GoTrain("Wow, you're too short for this obstacle")

except FellError :
  GoTrain("Wow, you fell! go work on your balance!")
```

Answer (score 1):

I just thought of the fact that i could use a `finally` block where i'll put the "mandatory" part for the execution, because other than in the analogy i made, the code in my use case goes like this :

```
try : 
  CopyDataFromAWebsite()
  PasteData() #This line won't execute if the website crashes let's say
except WebsiteCrash :
  #Print some things
  PasteData()
```

and so what i can do is :

```
try : 
  CopyDataFromWebsite()
except WebsiteCrash :
  #print some lines
finally : 
  PasteData()
```

This way i ensure that this function gets executed whatever happens, but i got to admit, it's a pretty rare usecase..

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).